# Got Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.3

am getting this error in cakephp on my server Fatal error:

`Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/u243273800/public_html/telecom/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php on line 331`

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking, and this is off-topic here anyway. If you think you have found a bug in the tool, report it on their project page. This site is for programming questions, or tools used primarily by programmers. That doesn't cover debugging library code (unless you've delved into the code yourself and have a programming related question about the bug you found).

Answer (score -2):

Your program has hit php's server memory limit.

There's a file called `php.ini` someplace in your server. (You'll need to look at your server to find it; it's often in the same directory with the php interpreter.) It contains some lines like this

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M
```

You can try to raise the memory_limit and restart php. If you're working on one of those $5 per month shared hosting services, you'll need to do this through the control panel if you can do it at all. Ask your support team.

You also may need to go over your program and try to reduce memory usage. It's possible that you are loading too many rows of a result set from your database.

Comment: There is a memory leak, this is not a solution to the problem! The leak should be tracked down and removed!